# Changing series names in a dynamic excel graph

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dynamic graph that changes the number of series that are plotted in excel, however, I would like a way of changing the series names in the legend to the Names that I have in other cells of a different sheet. I have the following code but I am not sure how to go about changing the letters in the Chart series line;

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim No_of_probes As Integer

Sheets("1. Paste Raw Data").Select
No_of_probes = Range("A2").Value

For i = 1 To No_of_probes

ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$C$4"

Next i
```

I want it to loop through like this incrementing in the same way for each pass of the For loop but I am not sure how to go about changing the letter or cell reference at the end? I am finding it hard to find an example that is similar to this anywhere.

```
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$C$4"
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(2).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$D$4"
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(3).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$E$4"
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(4).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$F$4"
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(5).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$G$4"
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(6).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$H$4"
   ' ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(7).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$I$4"
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(8).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$J$4"
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(9).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$K$4"
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(10).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$L$4"
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(11).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$M$4"
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(12).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$N$4"
    'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(13).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!$O$4"
```

Comment: You could use `Range.Address` to get the `$C$4`, `$D$4`, etc. Or you can use R1C1 notation as the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.series.name) point out.

Comment: Could you expand on this? I need to be able to iterate the letters of the alphabet based on the number of cells that are populated on a sheet. So if I had 13 cells populated I would need each For loop to change the end of the statement like 1 would be C 2 would be D 3 would be E etc.

Comment: Instead of iterating the letters of the alphabet, iterate through a `Range`... and then working with the address will have the same effect.

Answer (score 0):

This can be used:

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim No_of_probes As Integer

Sheets("1. Paste Raw Data").Select
No_of_probes = Range("A2").Value

For i = 1 To No_of_probes

    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!" & Range("C4").Offset(0, i - 1).Address

Next i
```

Comment: Thanks! I seem to be getting an object variable error when I run it on the following; 'ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(i).Name = "='1. Paste Raw Data'!" & Range("C4").Offset(0, i - 1).Address

Comment: You must select the chart, I think, because you used activechart

Comment: Then if you have selected your chart, you must ensure your series collection count same as no of probes

Comment: If you know the chart name, you can select the chart by program